# How do I install Visual Studio dll files?

Tags: c#, windows, dll

I want use the Scintilla controls and the RadControls for Winforms, but I do not know how to incorporate the files. They are in .dll format? How do I use the controls if they are in .dll format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would add them to the project you want to use them in, then add a reference, and then use them like any other dll.

For installing into the GAC, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28VS.80%29.aspx

Right click the project, click Add Reference, go to Browse tab, find them and add them.

Comment: right click in the toolbox (preferably a new tab in it), and click choose items. Then find the controls you wish to add (they should be under .NET Framework Components if you referenced it like I put above), check off the new controls then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

In the winforms toolbox, right click and "Choose Items...", then click the browse button and find the dll. Then go through the list of controls, and check the controls that you've added (usually it will do this step for you).

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/general/add-radcontrols-for-winforms-to-the-toolbox.aspx) knowledge base article on the Telerik website explains how to manually add the controls to the toolbox in Visual Studio.